# Qt - Shared Library Containing 'Utility' Functions?

Tags: c++, qt, utilities

Coming from non C++ background, I am trying to rewrite a few projects using Qt. I need to create a shared library that will house commonly used 'utility' functions. I do not need a class as all functions will be static so my thinking was to create a namespace that will contain all the functions however, accomplishing this using the Qt provided shared library template is not working. Is this possible? If so, can someone please point me in the right direction?

For example, I want to take the Utils functions below and put them into a shared library so that I do not have to copy the files into all projects where I want to use them.

**Utils.h**

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include <QtCore>
#include <QString>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QFileInfo>

namespace Utils {
    QString getAppName();
    bool stringToBool(const QString &str);
    QString getFileTimeStamp();
    QString getPacketTime();
    QString getTodayStamp();
}

#endif // UTILS_H
```

**Utils.cpp**

```
#include <Helpers/utils.h>

namespace Utils {

    QString getAppName()
    {
        return QFileInfo(QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()).baseName();
    }

    bool stringToBool(const QString &str)
    {
        return str.contains("1");
    }

    QString getFileTimeStamp()
    {
        return QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("ddhhmmsszzz");
    }

    QString getPacketTime()
    {
        return QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss");
    }

    QString getTodayStamp()
    {
        return QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("MMddyy");
    }

}
```

Comment: Unclear why Qt is used? What part of Qt will be used in that library? What functionality these functions from dynamic library implement?

Comment: Because Qt is the framework that I am using to rewrite the app and I am trying to make use of the shared library wizard within the Qt Creator IDE.

Comment: I see you have added code to the question. Very simplistic.

1. There will be dependence on Qt itself.
2. If it will not used by more than one app I would not even try to create dynamic library with Qt.
3. If it will be used by many independent apps but made with same Qt version then there is a reason for doing dynamic library, should it be large and complex enough to satisfy all the work.

If it will be used by just one app then you don't need dynamic library.

The wiki for you: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application

Comment: When you say "not working", please be a little more specific. What did you expect, and what actually happened? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from unfortunate includes in the header this looks OK code wise.

If you are building this as a shared library and the platform uses symbol hiding, then you need to "export" the functions.

This is usually done by having an "export macro" header, i.e. something like this

```
#include <qglobal.h>

#ifndef UTILS_EXPORT
# if defined(MAKE_UTILS_LIB)
   /* We are building this library */
#  define UTILS_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
# else
   /* We are using this library */
#  define UTILS_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
# endif
#endif
```

That is then being used to mark the symbols that should be visible at link time

```
#include "utils_export.h"

namespace Utils {
    UTILS_EXPORT QString getAppName();
}
```

The library's `.pro` file needs to set the `define` that triggers the export part of the macro

```
DEFINES += MAKE_UTILS_LIB=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I Created small Notepad Application which contains some Useful utilies for Qt project [QUtils - Utils for Qt](https://github.com/haseeb-heaven/NotepadQt/blob/master/Qutils.cpp)
Here is some list of method it contains.

```
//Public non-static methods. Invoke using 'g_Utils' instance.
//UI Dialogs,Information methods.
void Qt_ShowInfo(QString info_msg,QString title="INFO");
void Qt_ShowWarning(QString warning_msg,QString title="WARNING");
void Qt_ShowError(QString err_msg,QString title="ERROR");
int Qt_ShowDialog(QString dlg_msg,QString dlg_title);

//File Manipulation methods.
QString Qt_ShowOpenFileDlg(QString extension,bool log_dbg=false);
QString Qt_ShowOpenFileDlg(QString title,QString extension,QString init_path,bool log_dbg=false);
QString Qt_ShowSaveFileDlg(QString title,bool log_dbg=false);
QString Qt_ReadFile(QString file_name,bool log_dbg=false);
void Qt_WriteFile(QString file_name,QString file_data,bool log_dbg=false);
```